# Which methods can I use to recognize characters/letters without an OCR?

Tags: image-processing, ocr, tesseract, image-recognition, aforge

I want to know if there are some methods to recognize letters (my case is a little easier, I need to recognize only capital letters) without using an OCR.

At the moment my application can produce a binary version of each character, not very precise due to the bad resolution of the image, but good for the most of the images.
So I need a computational fast and reliable algorithm to recognize it.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to compare a Hu moments of charecter images
http://www.academia.edu/289447/Multi-Font_English_Character_Recognition_Based_on_Modified_Invariant_Moments

Comment: Wow, this can be a solution.
A little complicated to implement but a very good answer!